# Define a command based on lstlisting usable in the normal line of the text.

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

Is there a way in order to define a command of 1 argument (that we can call '\likelisting')  that allow us to inherits some defined things with lstlisting. For istance with the code

```
      \begin{lstlisting}
      int main(void)
      \end{lstlisting}
```

give me this as out put:

[image]

is there a way to have

```
        some text \likelisting{int main (void)} some text
```

and have as out put

[image]

but with the exacly style of lstlisting (so with the same 
gray highlighted that use lstlisting?

Comment: search for `\lstinline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is provided by [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)'s `\lstinline` macro. You can either use `\lstinline` directly, or create an alias:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset{
  language=c,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
\newcommand{\likelisting}{\lstinline}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{lstlisting}
int main(void)
\end{lstlisting}

some text \likelisting{int main(void)} some text

some text \likelisting[keywordstyle={\color{red}}]{int main(void)} some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is what I want. But how to have the same backgroundcolor? Why the command doesn't work in tabular?

Comment: @AndreaLeo: The documentation mentions the argument-style interface for `\lstinline` using `{`..`}` is experimental. I would image it is fragile in general (like most verbatim-like content) and therefore may be limited in its use (like in `tabular`). You can use an alternative delimiter (say) `\likelisting!...!`.Regarding the colour: That's a completely different problem. `\lstinline` does not support that (mentioned in the documentation as well; section **4.2 Typesetting listings**).

Comment: the command should work in tabular. like any verb command it won't work in the argument of another command or "fake" environments like `tabularx`